# how to show unix timestamp in blade view from created_at or updated_at field in database laravel?

Tags: laravel, datetime, eloquent, unix-timestamp

I want to get UNIX timestamp or convert created_at or updated_at date to UNIX timestamp format from database fields (created_at and updated_at) in laravel 5.8 , how can i do this?

**this is my code in my controller :**

```
public function viewArchives(){
$data = Archive::select(‘created_at’)->get();
return view(‘view.archives’, compact(‘data’));
}
```

**and in view/archives.blade.php :**

```
<?php echo $data;?>
```

**the result is :**

```
{“created_at”:”2019-03-17 19:10:30″}
```

**but i want the result be like this :**

```
{“created_at”:”1552849830″}
```

how can get this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$string = '2019-03-17 19:10:30';

$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->created_at = $string;

$collection = [$obj];

foreach ($collection as $k => &$v) {
    $collection[$k]->created_at = strtotime($v->created_at);
}

//var_dump($collection);
```

or

```
$string = '2019-03-17 19:10:30';

$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->created_at = $string;

$collection = [$obj];

array_walk($collection, function (&$item, $key) {
    $item->created_at = strtotime($item->created_at);
});

//var_dump($collection);
```

Or in your case

```
    public function viewArchives()
    {
        $data = Archive::select('created_at')->get();
        foreach ($data as $k => &$v) {
            $v->created_at = strtotime($v->created_at);
        }
        return view('view.archives', compact('data'));
    }
```

or

```
    public function viewArchives()
    {
        $data = Archive::select('created_at')->get();
        array_walk($data, function (&$item, $key) {
            $item->created_at = strtotime($item->created_at);
        });
        return view('view.archives', compact('data'));
    }
```

This is good place to use [`array_walk()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) function.

Comment: Thanks @Tpojka , Your solution Worked

Answer (score 0):

**Add strtotime() view/archives.blade.php :**

```
<?php echo strtotime( $data );?>
```

Comment: Using strtotime is right, but actually in his example `$data` is not just the date string, its a key value set.

Comment: @namelivia Your are right. First, get created_at value from `$data` and then convert strtotime.

Comment: @namelivia, Like that  `{{ $data['created_at'] }}` OR `{{ $data->created_at }}`

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya when i use this >>```{{ $data['created_at'] }}``` it says: Undefined index: created_at ... . And when i use this>>```{{ $data->created_at }}``` it says: Property [created_at] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: @AminArjmand In your controller change `get()` method to `toArray()`.  Like `$data = Archive::select(‘created_at’)->toArray();`  And use variable in blade `{{ $data['created_at'] }}`

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya , I changed to ```toArray()``` and the error is >> ```Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::toArray()```

Answer (score 0):

With an Eloquent `Model` one can actually define the `$casts` per column:

```
class SomeModel extends Model
{

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'created_at' => 'datetime'
    ];
}
```

If you want epoch timestamps instead, just remove this cast (which is likely present).

---

When the timestamp isn't from any Eloquent `Model`, one still can render it with Blade:

```
@php
$dt = new DateTime();
echo $dt->setTimestamp( $timestamp )->format("Y-m-d H:m:s");
@endphp
```

Or the other way around:

```
@php
echo strtotime( $isodate );
@endphp
```